# There are 2 same querysets in context for the ListView

Tags: python, django

I am wondering why there are 2 same querysets in the context: object_list and massage_list. Did I do something wrong? I could find massage_list only in urls `path('work/', MassageListView.as_view(), name='massage_list')`

```
class MassageListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Massage.objects.filter(time_of_receipt__year=now().year,
                                   time_of_receipt__month=now().month)

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(MassageListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        month_salary = 0
        for i in context['object_list']:
            month_salary += i.price
        context['month_salary'] = month_salary
        context['form'] = MassageForm()
        print(context)
        return context
```

printed context

```
{
  'paginator': None, 
  'page_obj': None, 
  'is_paginated': False, 
  'object_list': <QuerySet [<Massage: 2021-08-11 12:00:00+00:00>, <Massage: 2021-08-14 12:00:00+00:00>]>, 
  'massage_list': <QuerySet [<Massage: 2021-08-11 12:00:00+00:00>, <Massage: 2021-08-14 12:00:00+00:00>]>, 
  'view': <myapp.views.MassageListView object at 0x7f2e166200a0>, 
  'month_salary': 13800, 
  'form': <MassageForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(client;price;count;time_of_receipt)>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this method in the `MultipleObjectMixin` which is inherited by `BaseListView`.

```py
    def get_context_object_name(self, object_list):
        """Get the name of the item to be used in the context."""
        if self.context_object_name:
            return self.context_object_name
        elif hasattr(object_list, 'model'):
            return '%s_list' % object_list.model._meta.model_name
        else:
            return None
```

This method as can be seen returns `[model_name]_list` string, which is later used in the `get_context_data` method alongside with `object_list`.

```py
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        """Get the context for this view."""
        queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list

        ...       

        context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)

        ...   

        if context_object_name is not None:
            context[context_object_name] = queryset

        ...   

        return context
```

But don't worry, it's the same objects.

However it's weird that this is undocumented feature.